# drupal 6 authenticated user

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-7

In drupal 6 there is two by default role anonymous user and authenticated user.by mistake remove authenticated user.it create many problem for checking permission of authenticated user
so how to get authenticated user role.or(rollback that operation).

Answer (score 2):

Fire insert query in phpmyadmin

INSERT INTO `tablename`.`role` (`rid`, `name`) VALUES ('2', 'authenticated user')

Answer (score 2):

Instead of table name, use database name. Fire insert query in phpMmyAdmin like this:

```
INSERT INTO database name.role (rid, name) VALUES ('2', 'authenticated user')
```